# Задачи про ходы ферзя

Tags: c++, шахматы

Решаю задачу. Получил решение, но пишет "программа выдает неверный ответ"
Ходы ферзя
На шахматной доске стоит ферзь. Отметьте положение ферзя на доске и все клетки, которые бьет ферзь. Клетку, где стоит ферзь, отметьте буквой "Q", клетки, которые бьет ферзь, отметьте символами "*", остальные клетки заполните точками.

Входные данные

В двух строках входного файла заданы два числа — координаты нахождения ферзя. Числа во входном файле натуральные, не превосходящие 8 по значению.

Выходные данные

Выведите на экран изображение доски так, как это показано в примере. Обратите внимание, что символы в одной строке разделены пробелом.

````
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char d[8][8];
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=7;j++)
        {
            d[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    d[a-1][b-1]='Q';
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        if(i==b-1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            d[a-1][i]='*';
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        if(i==a-1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            d[i][b-1]='*';
        }
    }
    int j=b-1;
    for(int i=a;i<=7;i++)
    {
            j+=1;
            if(j==7)
            {
                d[i][j]='*';
                break;
            }
            else
            {
             d[i][j]='*';
            }
    }
    j=b-1;
    for(int i=a-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        j+=1;
        if(j==7)
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
        }
    }
    j=b-1;
    for(int i=a-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        j-=1;
        if(j==0)
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
        }
    }
    j=b-1;
    for(int i=a;i<=7;i++)
    {
        j-=1;
        if(j==0)
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            d[i][j]='*';
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=7;j++)
        {
            cout<<d[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Ну у вас вроде как только пробела не хватает, а так нормально? https://ideone.com/3CzyIJ Страшновато, да, можно проще - но работает. Так в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Нет. Добавил пробел, но не работает. С вводом 1 8 проблемы, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите этот код:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char d[8][8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            d[i][j]='.';
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    --a; --b;
    assert(a >= 0 && a < 8 && b >= 0 && b < 8);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            if (abs(i-a)==abs(j-b) || i == a || j == b) d[i][j] = '*';

    d[a][b]='Q';

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            cout << d[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подошло